# Loop with i-1 doesn't find correct value

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

Task:

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, returning 0 for an empty array. Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count and numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count.

Test sample, expected:

1. sum13([1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 13]) → 4
2. sum13([1, 2, 2, 1, 13]) → 6

My code yield following results:

```
  #sum13([1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 13]) → 3
  #sum13([1, 2, 2, 1, 13]) → 5

  def sum13(nums):
  s = 0
  if not nums:
    return 0
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i]==13 or nums[i-1]==13:
      s += 0
    else:
      s += nums[i]
  return s
```

Why it doesn't count number before last 13 num ?

UPD:

Thanks for comments, understand the problem. Correct like this:

```
  def sum13(nums):
  s = 0
  if not nums:
    return 0
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i]==13 or (nums[i-1]==13 and i-1>=0):
      s += 0
    else:
      s += nums[i]
  return s
```

Comment: What's the value of `i` in the first iteration?

Comment: Understand the mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because for your first pass of the loop, `i` is `-1`.

I think you can try this version to give you what you want:

```
def sum13(nums):
    s = 0
    if nums:
        prev = False
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if not prev and nums[i] != 13:
                s += nums[i]
            prev = nums[i] == 13
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is starting from 0 index so in first iteration you are checking if nums[0] == 13 or nums[-1] == 13 (in python -1 index will give you the last element of the list). So in both test case condition is true because last element is 13, that is the reason 1 is not being added in s.
Solution is to start your index from 1.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I was just suppose to tell the reason for wrong output not solution... The idea was just to give suggestion not the entire solution. I have removed solution part from my comment.

Comment: It's still the wrong solution suggestion. It's easy to test, if your index starts at 1 you have `sum13([1, 2, 3])` returns 5. Your solution successfully fixes the issue with the last element, but now it ignores the first element!